# Python: How to compare values of different keys in dictionary and then delete duplicates?

Tags: python

I am parsing over 100 files that follow the same format. For example for one file, I have a dictionary consisting of two keys and multiple values in a list.

```
   temp2 = {
  '0.1995': ['X3:GATE', 'IN1', 'IN1', 'X7:GATE', 'X4:GATE', 'IN2', 'IN2', 'X8:GATE'],
  '0.399': ['X4:GATE', 'Y', 'Y', 'X3:GATE', 'Y', 'X8:SRC', 'X1:GATE', 'IN0', 'IN0', 'X5:GATE']
```

Here is the code that creates the temp2 dictionary:

```
#temp_delvt_list, temp_pin_list is from an external function
for delvt, pin in zip(temp_delvt_list, temp_pin_list):
                temp[delvt].append(pin) #dictionary with delvt and pin names for cell

            for line in SPFFile1:
#                   print line
                for delvt_keys,pin_values in temp.items():
#                   if re.match('[RC].*(?:i%s)' % '|'.join(pin_values), line): //couldn't get working
                    if re.search('(?i)' '|'.join(pin_values),line) and re.match('R',line):
                        #print delvt_keys
                        line_split = line.split(" ")
                        temp_list.append(delvt_keys)
                        temp_list.append(delvt_keys) #duplicated to create balanced list with temp_search_list
                        temp_search_list.append(line_split[1])
                        temp_search_list.append(line_split[2])
#                       print temp_list
#                       print temp_search_list
            SPFFile1.close()
            for d, p in zip(temp_list, temp_search_list):
                #print temp2[d]
            #   print re.sub(':SRC',':ISI',p)
                temp2[d].append(p) #dictionary with delvt and pin names for cell
#           print temp2

}
```

I am trying to search the values for each key and then for the key (0.1995) with no Y-values delete all values that appear for that key that also appear in the key (0.399) that has the Y values.The key values are not hardcoded and may change.

The output should be:

```
temp2 = {
  '0.1995': ['X3:GATE', 'IN1', 'IN1', 'X7:GATE', 'X4:GATE', 'IN2', 'IN2', 'X8:GATE'],
  '0.399': ['Y', 'Y','Y', 'X8:SRC', 'X1:GATE', 'IN0', 'IN0', 'X5:GATE']
}
```

Here is the code I have figured out so far:

```
        for test_d, test_p in temp2.items():
            if not re.search('Y', ' '.join(test_p)) :
                for x in test_p:
                    print x
            else:
                for y in test_p:
                    print y
```

Where I think I should replace the print statement with either lists that I compare either other to.

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: Here you go where temp2 becomes temp2 = {
  '0.1995': ['X3:GATE', 'IN1', 'IN1', 'X7:GATE', 'X4:GATE', 'IN2', 'IN2', 'X8:GATE'],
  '0.399': ['Y', 'Y','Y', 'X8:SRC', 'X1:GATE', 'IN0', 'IN0', 'X5:GATE']
}   I deleted the duplicates X3:GATE and X4:GATE values from the 0.399 key.

Comment: I'm having problems understanding that (where do the *other* values come from?), in any case, please *update the original post/question* with the information. It is hard to read dense comments and the information is easily lost.

Comment: @pst I updated the original post with information, hope it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you are looking for

```
>>> temp2 = {
  '0.1995': ['X3:GATE', 'IN1', 'IN1', 'X7:GATE', 'X4:GATE', 'IN2', 'IN2', 'X8:GATE'],
  '0.399': ['X4:GATE', 'Y', 'Y', 'X3:GATE', 'Y', 'X8:SRC', 'X1:GATE', 'IN0', 'IN0', 'X5:GATE']
}
>>> _set = set(temp2['0.1995'])
>>> temp2['0.399'] = [e for e in temp2['0.399'] if e not in _set]
>>> import pprint
>>> pp = PrettyPrinter(indent = 4)
>>> pp.pprint(temp2)
{   '0.1995': [   'X3:GATE',
                  'IN1',
                  'IN1',
                  'X7:GATE',
                  'X4:GATE',
                  'IN2',
                  'IN2',
                  'X8:GATE'],
    '0.399': ['Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'X8:SRC', 'X1:GATE', 'IN0', 'IN0', 'X5:GATE']}
>>>
```

Comment: `if e not in set(temp2['0.1995'])` will be slower, not faster, than `if e not in temp2['0.1995']`, because it will recreate the set for every single item.

Comment: @DavidRobinson: It was rather indicative. In any case I updated my answer to create the set outside the comprehension.

Comment: @Abhijit I updated my OP to give some more clarifying details about how the dictionary is made. The keys may change when I parse a different file. How would I change your answer to work without the hardcoded keys?