# How to compare more than two keys in the same dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

I am parsing 100s of files that follow a similar format. From the file, I create a dictionary that may contain two keys or more than two keys where the values are in a set. Regardless, there will always be a key that contains the 'Y' value. For that key, I need to remove any duplicate values that exist in the other keys.

I had a similar problem where I only had two keys and it was solved. [Python: How to compare values of different keys in dictionary and then delete duplicates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14350899/python-how-to-compare-values-of-different-keys-in-dictionary-and-then-delete-du)

The below code works fine when the dictionary has two keys but not more than two.

```
for d, p in zip(temp_list, temp_search_list):
    temp2[d].add(p) #dictionary with delvt and pin names for cell
for test_d, test_p in temp2.items():
    if not re.search('Y', ' '.join(test_p)) :
         tp = temp2[test_d]
    else:
         temp2[test_d] = [t for t in temp2[test_d] if t not in tp]
```

Example dictionary that uses three keys but depending on the parsed file I can have more keys.

```
temp2 = {'0.1995': set(['X7:GATE', 'X3:GATE', 'IN1']), '0.199533': set(['X4:GATE', 'X8:GATE', 'IN2']), '0.399': set(['X3:GATE', 'X5:GATE', 'X1:GATE', 'IN0', 'X4:GATE', 'Y', 'X8:GATE'])}
```

Expected Output:

```
temp2
{'0.1995': set(['X7:GATE', 'X3:GATE','IN1']), '0.199533': set(['X4:GATE', 'X8:GATE', 'IN2']), '0.399': set(['X5:GATE', 'X1:GATE', 'IN0', 'Y'])}
```

Comment: `any('Y' in value for value in test_p)` would be a better way to test for the presence of `Y`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to separate the search for the `Y` value from the search through the rest of you data. You really want to do that when you are already building `temp2`, to avoid unnecessary loops:

```
y_key = None
for d, p in zip(temp_list, temp_search_list):
    temp2[d].add(p)
    if p == 'Y':
        y_key = d
```

Next, removing the dupe values is easiest using [`set.difference_update()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set.difference_update) to alter the sets in-place:

```
y_values = temp2[y_key]
for test_d, test_p in temp2.iteritems():
    if test_d == y_key:
        continue
    y_values.difference_update(test_p)
```

Using your example `temp2`, and presuming that `y_key` has already been set while building `temp2`, the result of the second loop is:

```
>>> temp2 = {'0.1995': set(['X7:GATE', 'X3:GATE', 'IN1']), '0.199533': set(['X4:GATE', 'X8:GATE', 'IN2']), '0.399': set(['X3:GATE', 'X5:GATE', 'X1:GATE', 'IN0', 'X4:GATE', 'Y', 'X8:GATE'])}
>>> y_key = '0.399'
>>> y_values = temp2[y_key]
>>> for test_d, test_p in temp2.iteritems():
...     if test_d == y_key:
...         continue
...     y_values.difference_update(test_p)
... 
>>> temp2
{'0.1995': set(['X7:GATE', 'X3:GATE', 'IN1']), '0.199533': set(['X4:GATE', 'X8:GATE', 'IN2']), '0.399': set(['X5:GATE', 'X1:GATE', 'IN0', 'Y'])}
```

Note how the values `X3:GATE`, `X4:GATE` and `X8:GATE` have been removed from the `0.399` set.

Comment: Hi @Martijn I actually want the duplicates to be removed from the set that contains 'Y'. I'll update the OP to show the expected outcome.

Comment: @JonA.: That's easy enough. Updated to reverse the `difference_update()` variables, and the produced output.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the whole thing with only 1 loop that actually has to traverse the entire dataset.

```
from collections import defaultdict

target = None
result = defaultdict(set)
occurance_dict = defaultdict(int)
# Loop over the inputs, building the result, counting the
# number of occurances for each value as you go and marking
# the key that contains 'Y'
for key, value in zip(temp_list, temp_search_list):
    # This is here so we don't count values twice if there
    # is more than one instance of the value for the given
    # key.  If we don't do this, if a value only exists in
    # the 'Y' set, but it occurs multiple times in the input,
    # we would still filter it out later on.
    if value not in result[key]:
        occurance_dict[value] += 1
        result[key].add(value)
    if value == 'Y':
        if target is None:
            target = key
        else:
            raise ValueError('Dataset contains more than 1 entry containing "Y"')
if target is None:
    raise ValueError('Dataset contains no entry containing "Y"')
# Filter the marked ('Y' containing) entry; if there is more than
# 1 occurance of the given value, then it exists in another entry
# so we don't want it in the 'Y' entry
result[target] = {value for value in result[target] if occurance_dict[value] == 1}
```

Yes `occurance_dict` is the much same as a `collections.Counter`, but I'd rather not iterate over the dataset twice (even if it is happening behind the scenes) if I don't have to, and we also aren't counting a second occurance of a given value for the same key.

Answer (score 0):

I wish I could think of a cute way to do this with list comprehensions and/or the itertools module, but I can't. I'd start with something like:

```
dict1 = {1: set([1,2,3,4,5]),
         2: set([3,4,5,6]),
         3: set([1,7,8,9])
        }

list1 = dict1.items()
newDict = {}
for i in range(len(list1)):
    (k1,set1) = list1[i]
    newDict[k1] = set1
    for j in range(i+1,len(list1)):
        (k2, set2) = list1[j]
        newDict[k2] = set2 - (set1 & set2)

print newDict 
# {1: set([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]), 2: set([6]), 3: set([8, 9, 7])}
```

This is probably not super efficient if you have huge dictionaries.

Another idea: are the sets too long so that you can't just form a `collection.Counter`? You would first go through the dict and strip out the members in each set and stick them in a counter (probably can be doen in one line wiht a list comprehension). Then, loop through `originalDict.iteritems()`. Into a new dict, you can insert the key (i.e., 0.1995) whose value is the original set, filtered (use `&` as above, I think) so that it only contains entries in the counter with counts > 0. For all elements that you inserted into the new dictionary, remove them from the counter (even if they have >1 counts). At the end of the day, you still have to loop twice though.

Answer (score 0):

Seems pretty straight-forward to me. First find the key that has a `'Y'` in its set of value, then go though the all the other sets of values and remove them from that set of values.

```
temp2 = {'0.1995':  set(['X7:GATE', 'X3:GATE', 'IN1']),
         '0.199533':set(['X4:GATE', 'X8:GATE', 'IN2']),
         '0.399':   set(['X3:GATE', 'X5:GATE', 'X1:GATE', 'IN0', 'X4:GATE', 'Y', 'X8:GATE'])}

y_key = None
for k,v in temp2.iteritems():
    if 'Y' in v:
        y_key = k
        break

if y_key is None:
    print "no 'Y' found in values"
    exit()

result = {}
for k,v in temp2.iteritems():
    if k != y_key:
        temp2[y_key] -= v

print 'temp2 = {'
for k,v in temp2.iteritems():
    print '  {!r}: {!r},'.format(k,v)
print '}'
```

Output:

```
temp2 = {
  '0.1995': set(['X7:GATE', 'X3:GATE', 'IN1']),
  '0.199533': set(['X4:GATE', 'X8:GATE', 'IN2']),
  '0.399': set(['X5:GATE', 'X1:GATE', 'IN0', 'Y']),
}
```